# My api call is receiving a 405 error

Tags: javascript, database, api

My api call is receiving a 405 error. Don't know why. It seems like it should connect, but I'm receiving bupkis

```
  $("#folio_input").bind("focus", function(event) {
    $(this).autocomplete( "search", "" );
  }).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(req, add){
      $.ajax({
        url:'/api/parcels/search',
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'type=parcels&folionumber='+folionumber+'&q='+req.term,
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        success: function(data){
          add($.map(data, function(item) {
            return item;
          }));
          load_docs();
        }
      });
    },
```

Comment: First of all, correct form of passing post params is 
`data: {type: 'parcels', folionumber: folionumber, q:req.term}`. Also double check the method `POST` is allowed for this endpoint.

Comment: @Vikas I started getting some feedback with that, thank you very much.

Comment: @Vikas That is only if the server is expecting JSON input, what he has is perfectly valid for application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @ClassicalVampire the status code 405 is Method Not Allowed, based on the data i would say try using type: 'GET' instead. It doesn't look like the server is allowing POST to that endpoint.

Comment: @AdamH That's exactly what I did (along with correcting the post params). Thank you

Comment: @ClassicalVampire Glad I could help